# In R, manipulating a time series with lag

Tags: r, time-series

I have a ts date like this:

```
> class(ts_data)
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
>head(ts_data)
              observation 
2000 Q1       -0.09454545 
2000 Q2       -0.08354839 
2000 Q3       -0.13312500 
2000 Q4       -0.12131148 
2001 Q1       -0.75129032 
2001 Q2       -0.70147541
```

For each observation t, I'd like to create a new variable:

```
new_variable[t] <- observation[t-1] + observation[t] + observation[t+1]
```

In R, I do this

```
new_variable <-  lag(ts_data[,1] ,1) + ts_data[,1]  + lag(ts_data[,1] ,-1)

ts_data <- ts.intersect(ts_data,new_variable )

> head(ts_data)
              observation            new_variable
2000 Q2       -0.08354839              -0.3112188
2000 Q3       -0.13312500              -0.3379849
2000 Q4       -0.12131148              -1.0057268
2001 Q1       -0.75129032              -1.5740772
2001 Q2       -0.70147541              -1.4963595
2001 Q3       -0.04359375              -0.1631019
```

But It is not good. We can see that the variable "observation" is one other and the "new variable" is wrong. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: I don't see a problem, this is working as you want it except for first and last observation as they dont have the lower or upper lags respectively.